# Create redundant vlan attachment for partner interconnect with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-interconnect

I couldn't find this anywhere or a more specific forum, if there is any please redirect me.

Does the Google cloud terraform provider support the creation of a redundant pair of vlan attachments for Partner Interconnect? Either in a single action or in two steps (creating a standalone vlan and adding a redundant pair later).

I guess not, so a second question: If I create two VLAN attachments in two actions, one in each zone, is that covered by the 99.9% SLA?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first question, yes.  You can either think of each attachment as a separate resource, or use count to create multiple resources.  I prefer the later and have an example here:

https://github.com/jeheyer/terraform-modules/tree/main/google_compute_interconnect_attachment

Answer (score 0):

for the second question, yes that is covered by 99.9.

cloud router (us-east4)  - 2 vlan attachments on each zone - 99.9%

2 cloud routers (us-east4,us-central1)- 4 vlan attachments ( 2 in each region) -  99.99%

Comment: this helps. I'll create the 2 vlan attachments in two steps. Thanks!